# Return user defined structure to dynamic array element

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, dynamic-arrays

I am trying to create a dynamic array to store a linked list in each element of the array. So I defined the linked list structure as below:

```
//data type for adjacent bus stop
typedef struct AdjStopNode
{
    int distance; //travel distance from the bus original stop to this adjcent stop
    int stopID;
    struct AdjStopNode *prev; //pointer to previous bus stop
    struct AdjStopNode *next; //pointer to next bus stop
} AdjStopNode;

AdjStopNode *newAdjStopNode(int distance, int stopID)
{
    AdjStopNode *newNode = (AdjStopNode *)malloc(sizeof(AdjStopNode));
    assert(newNode != NULL);
    newNode->distance = distance;
    newNode->stopID = stopID;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    return newNode;
}

typedef struct AdjStopList
{
    char stopname[20]; 
    int numOfAdjStp;   
    struct BusAtStopList *buslist;  
    struct AdjStopNode *first; //pointed at the first AdjBusStop of the linked list
    struct AdjStopNode *last;  //pointed at the first AdjBusStop of the linked list
} AdjStopList;

AdjStopList *newAdjStopList()
{
    AdjStopList *newList = (AdjStopList *)malloc(sizeof(AdjStopList));
    newList->buslist = newBusAtStopList();
    assert(newList != NULL);
    memset(newList, NULL, 20 * sizeof(newList[0]));
    newList->first = NULL;
    newList->last = NULL;
    newList->numOfAdjStp = 0;
    return newList;
}
```

Then I defined a dynamic array to store each `AdjStopList` as an element of the array is as below:

```
typedef struct BusNetwork
{
    int nBusStop; //number of bus stops in the newwork
    struct AdjStopList *array;
} BusNetwork;
```

My function to assign an empty `AdjStopList` to every element of the array is as below:

```
//n is the number of AdjStopList
void listToArray(int n)
{
    BusNetwork *newBN;
    newBN = malloc(sizeof(BusNetwork));
    assert(newBN != NULL);
    newBN->nBusStop = n;
    newBN->array = malloc(n * sizeof(AdjStopList)); //create an array of n number of dejacency lists
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        newBN->array[i] = newAdjStopList();
    }
}
```

The above code gives me the error at `newBN->array[i] = newAdjStopList()` as

```
a value of type "AdjStopList *" cannot be assigned to an 
entity of type "struct AdjStopList" C/C++(513)
```

using VScode.

Could someone help me to fix this problem and explain to me why? Much appreciated.

Comment: The `BusNetwork` structure member `array` is an "array" of `AdjStopList` structure objects. The `newAdjStopList` function returns a *pointer to* a `AdjStopList` structure object. `struct AdjStopList` versus `struct AdjStopList *`.

Comment: OT: Your `listToArray` is wrong... `newBN` is never returned.... so all it does is to leak memory

Comment: OT: This `memset(newList, NULL, 20 * sizeof(newList[0]));` looks strange... what do you expect this to do?

Comment: I was trying to assign `NULL' to all the elements of the arrary, isn't it the right way? Sorry I am very new to programming

Comment: Thank you for highlighting this. Actually this code was partially finished....I paused when I had this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of `newBN->array` is `struct AdjStopList *` so the type of `newBN->array[i]` is `struct AdjStopList` but the return type from`newAdjStopList()` is `struct AdjStopList*`. So that should explain the error that you see where you are assigning a `struct AdjStopList*` to `struct AdjStopList` in the line

```
newBN->array[i] = newAdjStopList();
```

I believe you should change

```
typedef struct BusNetwork
{
    int nBusStop; //number of bus stops in the newwork
    struct AdjStopList *array;
} BusNetwork;
```

to

```
typedef struct BusNetwork
{
    int nBusStop; //number of bus stops in the newwork
    struct AdjStopList **array;
} BusNetwork;
```

So that `array` becomes an array of *pointers to* `struct AdjStopList`. Then that original assignment should work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It does fix the issue. So my understanding from you is that `*array` just creates a pointer to the dynamic array but not pointing to each element of the array? What if I wanted to create a static array to store `AdjStopList's?

Comment: That's right. Step back and simplify it as `int * x`. Here `x` could be made an array of `int`s. But `x` won't point to any element within the array (apart from the first element obviously). For referencing any element in the array, one would need `x[i]` to retrieve an `int` which is equivalent to `*(x + i)` i.e. the address pointed to by `i` blocks after `x` and then dereferencing it. Same is the case here.

Comment: By static array, you mean something like `static struct AdjStopList[10]`?

Comment: I see. I am having another issue since I changed it to `struct AdjStopList *array `. For example, if I wanted to assess `stopname` in one of the `AdjStopList` by saying `strcpy(newBN->array[i].stopname, "test")` gives me a similar error. Double pointer is very confusing to me still......

Comment: If you changed it to the double pointer version `struct AdjStopList **array`, then to access the `stopname` member, you'd need `newBN->array[i]->stopname` since now ``newBN->array[i]` is a pointer and not a concrete `struct`. Treat each _level_ of pointer separately. You have `struct AdjStopList **array`. Dereferencing one level i.e. `array[i]` yields `struct AdjStopList *` (a pointer to struct AdjStopList). Now it's just like accessing a regular pointer. So you use the `->` operator to access the member variables.

Comment: I fixed the above problem by changing it to `strcpy(*newBN->array[i]->stopname, stopName);` But I dont fully understand why...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231317/discussion-between-bobby-li-and-zoso).