# Access each element of a dynamic array in c

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I am using VScode as my IDE. So I created an array, and each element of the array stores a pointer to a linked list. My code is shown as below:

```
typedef struct AdjStopList
{
    char stopName[20]; //name of stop bus is equal or less than 20 characters
    int numOfAdjStp;   //number of adjacent stops to this stop
    struct BusAtStopList *buslist;  // store all the buses passing this stop in a linked list
    struct AdjStopNode *first; //pointed at the first AdjBusStop of the linked list
    struct AdjStopNode *last;  //pointed at the first AdjBusStop of the linked list
} AdjStopList;

typedef struct BusNetwork
{
    int nBusStop; //number of bus stops in the newwork
    struct AdjStopList **array;
} BusNetwork;

//create a new empty AdjBusStopList
AdjStopList *newAdjStopList()
{
    AdjStopList *newList = (AdjStopList *)malloc(sizeof(AdjStopList));
    newList->buslist = newBusAtStopList();
    assert(newList != NULL);
   // memset(newList, NULL, 20 * sizeof(newList[0]));
    newList->first = NULL;
    newList->last = NULL;
    newList->numOfAdjStp = 0;
    return newList;
}
```

I tried to use a while loop to assign `stopName` with `"test"` in a function

```
BusNetwork *newBusNetwork(int n, const char *BusStops)
{
    newBN->array = malloc(n * sizeof(AdjStopList*)); 

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        newBN->array[i] = newAdjStopList();
        strcpy(newBN->array[i]->stopName, "test");
    }
        
    //rest of the function
}
```

Then when I watch the variable `(struct AdjStopList (**)[46])newBN->array` in VScode, it seems only the first element of the array has been processed correctly, e.g. `newBN->array[0]->stopName` is `test`. The rest elements of the array still have random garbage values, e.g. `newBN->array[1]->stopName`.

Can anyone see why this is happening, please?

Comment: The reason why I used a double pointer is because of my another question...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67161189/return-user-defined-structure-to-dynamic-array-element/67161358?noredirect=1#comment118714687_67161358

Answer (score 1):

The initial value of buffer allocated via `malloc()` is indeterminate and using the (indeterminate) value invokes *undefined behavior*.

You have to initialize the pointers before using them.

Also note that the elements of the array pointed at by `newBN->array` is `struct AdjStopList *`, so `sizeof(struct AdjStopList *)` or `sizeof(newBN->array[0])` should be multiplied instead of `sizeof(AdjStopList)`.

```
BusNetwork *newBusNetwork(int n, const char *BusStops)
{
    /* correct allocation size */
    newBN->array = malloc(n * sizeof(newBN->array[0])); 
    /* check if allocation succeeded */
    if (newBN->array == NULL) return NULL;

    /* make sure not to cause out-of-range access */
    for (int i = 0; i < n && i < 10; i++)
    {
        /* initialize the element */
        newBN->array[i] = malloc(sizeof(*newBN->array[i]));
        /* check if allocation succeeded */
        if (newBN->array[i] != NULL)
        {
            strcpy(newBN->array[i]->stopName, "test");
        }
    }
        
    //rest of the function
}
```

Comment: Note that in relation to OP's previous question, where you initialize the element, you would call your `newAdjStopList` instead of `malloc` because that would allocate the memory.

Comment: Sorry I have edited my question to include the malloc. It still causes me the same problem though....